# How to print a linked list into a file

Tags: java, linked-list, fileoutputstream

Each linkedlist has a ISBN, authors name, book date, book price and I'm trying to save the whole book catalog (x many books) as a file. They said there is an error at

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 21
at BookCatalog.SaveFile(BookCatalog.java:34)
at BookCatalogClient.menu(BookCatalogClient.java:167)
at BookCatalogClient.main(BookCatalogClient.java:25)
```

which java:167 = for(Book newBook: g.SaveFile())

Here is the code:

from class 1:

```
PrintStream out = new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream("books.txt"));
for(Book newBook: g.SaveFile()){
out.println(newBook.getBookISBN()+"\t"+newBook.getLastName()+"\t"
+newBook.getFirstName()+"\t"+newBook.getTitle()+"\t"+newBook.getYearOfPublication()+"\t"+newBook.getPrice());

}
```

from class 2:

count is a global var that keeps how many books are in the catalog.

```
public Book[] SaveFile(){

   Book cursor = head;
   Book[] bookCount = new Book[count-1];
   int i = 0;
   while(cursor!=null){
       Book out = cursor;
       cursor = cursor.getNext();
       bookCount[i] = out;
       i++;

   }
   return bookCount;
```

}

Comment: Sorry it's a linked list into a file not a arraylist

Comment: So what exactly is your problem?

Comment: It makes the file, but nothing is saving into the file, then produce that message.

Comment: Yes, because your `SaveFile` method throws an exception - a pretty clear one at that, so you should be easily able to debug your code

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What causes a java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException and how do I prevent it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5554734/what-causes-a-java-lang-arrayindexoutofboundsexception-and-how-do-i-prevent-it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is incomplete i cant make out what is `head`  in your code. what

```
  cursor = cursor.getNext();
   bookCount[i] = out;
```

How cursor will become null ultimately your while loop is running infinitely. Please check
and you have to careful with

```
Book[] bookCount = new Book[count-1];
```

here the  size of array is also playing role check

Try changing book[] to `ArrayList<Book>`  i,e change declaration

```
Book[] bookCount = new Book[count-1];
```

to `ArrayList<Book> bookCount = new ArrayList<Book>();`
 and change code `bookCount[i]=cursor` to `bookCount.add(cursor)`

and try

otherwise change

```
 Book[] bookCount = new Book[count];
```

and check

Comment: It's a linked list not an arraylist.. sorry!

Comment: It works, but now it saids "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException"

Answer (score 0):

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 21

This exception only displays if you've gone beyond the arrays range.
So for the while loop you want to do something like this

```
while (cursor < counter)//Or something
......
```

Does this make sense?

Comment: `cursor` is of type `Book` and `counter` is an integer type, so this comparison doesn't make sense

Comment: I was using that as an example.
 From what I understand they need to have a while(a < b) sort of loop to prevent the loop from accessing something that's not in the loop

Answer (score 0):

There's a problem with your `count` variable in `class2`. How did you initialize it? The exception is coming because your array is of size 20 and you are inserting a `Book` at index `21`

Comment: count is a global var